# MulterError: Unexpected field at wrappedFileFilter With 2 files on different folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

First of all, I apologize for my English.
I'm having some trouble with uploading files using Multer and Express.

I'm trying to upload two files to two different folders, but I always get the message "MulterError: Unexpected field at wrappedFileFilter" message. I've also tried using just "uploadVideo" or "uploadImage," but the error remains the same.
I have created the "videos" and "imagenes" folders

I'm just starting with Multer.
I'm using the code below:

**multer.js**

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const multerVideo = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req,file,cb) => {
        const rutaVideo = path.join(__dirname + 'videos');
        cb(null,rutaVideo);
    },
    filename: (req, file,cb) => {
        const nombreVideo = Date.now() + path.extname(file.fieldname);
        cb(null,nombreVideo);
    }
});
const multerImage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req,file,cb) => {
        const rutaImagen = path.join(__dirname + 'imagenes');
        cb(null,rutaImagen);
    },
    filename: (req, file,cb) => {
        const nombreImagen = Date.now() + file.fieldname;
        cb(null,nombreImagen);
    }
});

const updateVideo = multer({Storage: multerVideo}).single('video');
const updateImage = multer({storage: multerImage}).single('imagen');

module.exports = {
    updateVideo,
    updateImage
}
```

**router.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('./multer');

router.get('/',(req,res) => {
 res.render('index');
});

router.post('/subir',multer.updateVideo, multer.updateImage,(req,res) =>{
    res.send('success?')
});


module.exports = router;
});
```

**index.js**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const indexRoute = require('./router');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.use('/',indexRoute);
app.listen(port,() => {
    console.log(`Servidor escuchando en el puerto ${port}`);
})
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MULTER PROBE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-container">
            <form action="/subir" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="video" id="video" class="video">
                <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen" class="imagen">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" class="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, that won't work, single middleware will parse all fields provided.

It seems you only change destination folder, so you can handle it in a single middleware, in `destination` method.

So, merge two middewares into one, and then in `destination` method, check each `fieldname` manually, and then construct the desired path for each (you can do the same for file under `filename`)

check `fieldname`:

```
destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.fieldname === 'video') {
```

and so on.

Try this:

**router.js**

```
// use single middleware
router.post('/subir', multer.upload, (req, res) => {
    res.send('success?')
});
```

**multer.js**

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const uploadStorage = multer.diskStorage({

    // in each method, check `file.fieldname`
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.fieldname === 'video') {
            const rutaVideo = path.join(__dirname + 'videos');
            cb(null, rutaVideo);
        } else if (file.fieldname === 'imagen') {
            const rutaImagen = path.join(__dirname + 'imagenes');
            cb(null, rutaImagen);
        } else {
            // some default fallback..      

        }
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.fieldname === 'video') {
            const nombreVideo = Date.now() + path.extname(file.fieldname);
            cb(null, nombreVideo);
        } else if (file.fieldname === 'imagen') {
            const nombreImagen = Date.now() + file.fieldname;
            cb(null, nombreImagen);
        } else {
            // some fallback
        }
    }
});


// use .any() to handle fields manually
const upload = multer({
    Storage: uploadStorage
}).any();


module.exports = {
    upload
}
```